# 'htdocs' folder in XAMPP for linux belongs to "nobody" after installing, why?

Tags: linux, permissions, xampp, htdocs, lampp

after installing XAMPP on linux i have seen the folder "htdocs" belongs to "nobody".

Has this any intention? Do you think owning that folder is a good practice?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *security* reasons.

It also means that apache should be also running as "nobody" and have read access to **htdocs**.

Some Linux distributions use "nobody" for servers and daemons while others create a user for each service (e.g mysql user, apache user)